# How to limit concurrent access to a single real-time resource

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, real-time

I'm trying to identify or understand an appropriate technique, idiom, whatever for a specific concurrent programming problem I'm having.

For simplicity's sake, assume I have a real-time graphical user interface (UI) that is redrawn on screen at 10Hz always and forever.

I would like to display a "Busy" indicator on this UI whenever at least one instance of a group of different threads are running, and I want that indicator to stop displaying when precisely 0 of these threads are running. These threads could feasibly be started and stopped at any time as long as the UI is up.

I'm currently implementing this in golang (with relevant snippets further below). But in general, I'm solving this as follows:

- Keep R+W access to a counter int `waitCount` (number of threads requesting we indicate "Busy") protected via mutex `waitLock`.
- function `drawStatus()`: Redraw the entire UI (occurs every 100ms):

  1. acquire mutex `waitLock`
  2. if int `waitCount` > 0:

     2. draw the "Busy" indicator
  3. release mutex `waitLock`
- function `startWait()`: When a thread needs to indicate busy:

  1. acquire mutex `waitLock`
  2. increment int `waitCount`
  3. release mutex `waitLock`
- function `stopWait()`: When a thread no longer needs to indicate busy:

  1. acquire mutex `waitLock`
  2. decrement int `waitCount`
  3. release mutex `waitLock`

To me, it feels like I'm not taking full advantage of golang's concurrency facilities and resorting to the mutexes I'm familiar with. But even still, there is a bug in this code wherein the "Busy" indicator gets dismissed prematurely.

I'm honestly not looking for anyone to help identify that bug, but rather I'm trying to convey the specific logic I'm interested in. Is there a more idiomatic golang way to approach this problem? Or is there a more general programming pattern that I should investigate? Does this technique I'm using have any particular name? And suggestions or pointers on doing this properly would be great. Thanks.

---

And here's some doctor'd up snippets that implement the above logic

```js
    var WaitCycle = [...]rune{'', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''}

    // type Layout holds the high level components of the terminal user interface
    type Layout struct {
        //
        // ... other fields hidden for example ...
        //
        waitLock  sync.Mutex
        waitIndex int // the current index of the "busy" rune cycle
        waitCount int // the current number of tasks enforcing the "busy" state
    }

    // function show() starts drawing the user interface.
    func (l *Layout) show() *ReturnCode {

        // timer forcing a redraw @ 10Hz
        go func(l *Layout) {
            tick := time.NewTicker(100 * time.Millisecond)
            defer tick.Stop()
            for {
                select {
                case <-tick.C:
                    // forces the UI to redraw all changed screen regions
                    l.ui.QueueUpdateDraw(func() {})
                }
            }
        }(l)

        if err := l.ui.Run(); err != nil {
            return rcTUIError.specf("show(): ui.Run(): %s", err)
        }
        return nil
    }

    // function drawStatus() draws the "Busy" indicator at a specific UI position
    func (l *Layout) drawStatus(...) {

        l.waitLock.Lock()
        if l.waitCount > 0 {
          l.waitIndex = (l.waitIndex + 1) % WaitCycleLength
          waitRune := fmt.Sprintf(" %c ", WaitCycle[l.waitIndex])
          drawToScreen(waitRune, x-1, y, width)
        }
        l.waitLock.Unlock()
    }

    // function startWait() safely fires off the "Busy" indicator on the status bar
    // by resetting the current index of the status rune cycle and incrementing the
    // number of goroutines requesting the "Busy" indicator.
    func (l *Layout) startWait() {
        l.waitLock.Lock()
        if 0 == l.waitCount {
          l.waitIndex = 0
        }
        l.waitCount++
        l.waitLock.Unlock()
    }

    // function stopWait() safely hides the "Busy" indicator on the status bar by
    // decrementing the number of goroutines requesting the "Busy" indicator.
    func (l *Layout) stopWait() {
        l.waitLock.Lock()
        l.waitCount--
        l.waitLock.Unlock()
    }
```

Comment: See[Mutex or Channel](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/MutexOrChannel).  Key points: use sync.Mutex for state as in the problem; don't be afraid to use sync.Mutex if it fits your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all you're doing is locking on a single counter, you could simplify and just use the [sync/atomic](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) package. Call `AddInt32(&x, 1)` when starting a goroutine, and `AddInt32(&x, -1)` when ending it. Call `LoadInt32(&x)` from your drawing goroutine.

Comment: i wasn't aware of these atomic routines available in the standard lib. they reduce the size of critical sections, but they also increase the number of them. not sure yet which is easier to read, but this combined with @ThunderCat comment i'm more confident in my approach. thanks a bunch

Comment: and for the record, the 64-bit flavor of these atomic routines have [a very easily overlooked bug](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#pkg-note-BUG) when running on 32-bit x86/ARM. be mindful of how you align 64-bit struct fields accessed via those routines... also, see [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/599)

Answer (score 1):

It is use case dependent (and you may choose what you wish, and no body cares until you produce a bug or hit the performance penalty), Channels hide Lock inside and make the coding **simpler** with a little performance cost - so I recommend using channels for the general use cases unless you are considering more  performance):
Use channels if:
1 - transferring ownership
2 - coordinating

Use primitives if:
3 - **performance critical**
4 - Guarding internal state of struct
ref: [page 33](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920046189.do)

---

Since you are using soft real time UI coordinating the number of goroutines, and **not performance critical** code, I recommend using channels, I simplified your code **here in this example**:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        go job() // e.g.: run all jobs
    }
    busy := 0
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond) // or make sure at least on goroutine started
    // 10Hz:
    tick := time.NewTicker(100 * time.Millisecond)
    defer tick.Stop()
    for {
        select {
        case n := <-ch:
            busy += n
        case <-tick.C:
            // forces the UI to redraw all changed screen regions
            fmt.Printf(" %d    \r", busy)
            if busy == 0 {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

func job() {
    ch <- +1
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(2000)) * time.Millisecond)
    ch <- -1
}

var ch = make(chan int, 1)
```

Comment: I wouldn't call this coordination. I don't know the book, so I don't know if the author defined her use of the term, but to me it includes some kind of before/after relationship of goroutines. On the hand a counter is certainly state, and using a mutex to protect it seems much simpler than sending increments over a channel. I have never seen this in real code so far. Calling it "more idiomatic" than a mutex is a stretch.

Comment: @Peter: Hi, Thanks for the comment, I made it more clear, do you agree with this now?

Comment: Not really, but I don't have to. I was just offering another point of view.

Comment: sorry i wasn't entirely clear, but i'm not coordinating the number of goroutines from the UI; i'm trying to reflect the current state of goroutines via UI (goroutines spawned from non-UI related events). also i'm admittedly not that familiar with go, so this approach was initially more difficult for me to understand versus traditional mutex primitives.